# Is there a product I could apply on the wall before painting so that one paint layer only will do?

Tags: walls, paint

After removing wallpaper with a steamer I want to paint it, but using the least amount of paint possible.

Is there a product I could apply on the wall before painting so that one paint layer only will do?

Comment: If you gonna buy primer.. you might as well buy a larger pot of paint and paint two layers of paint instead of 1 layer of primer and 1 layer of paint?!?

Comment: why do you want the least amount of paint possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a primer, like Zinsser Bulls Eye 1-2-3 or any other interior primer. It's rather hard to get true one coat coverage, why do you want only 1 coat? Are you trying to use an existing paint leftover to match the rest of the room? If so, you can buy tintable primer to better match the final color. We had to to this in a bright pink bedroom, so we tinted the primer blue, applied one coat of primer and topcoated with 2 coats of regular blue semi-gloss; worked quite well to hide such a strong color. You might get away with only one coat if the tint is relatively close. Check your local Sherwim Williams, Lowes, HD et cetera to see if they do tinted primers. Sherwin Williams is usually the best bet for special stuff.

Comment: Better than a colored tint for the primer when using a strong colored paint is using a dark gray primer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're main goal is to minimize the amount of paint you have to apply then a Primer/Paint combo is probably the way to go. It's hard to say though whether one coat will get satisfactory coverage though.  You'll get the best results if you don't try to change the color from one extreme to another.

Comment: I have yet to find a primer+paint that actually works with one coat. (The latest, a Behr, took 3 coats, albeit it was a lighter color going over darker on a textured wall)